# autofill textbox based on user input

Tags: asp.net, webforms, textbox, autofill

I'm extremely new to ASP.NET and came across a problem I have yet to figure out. On my Default.aspx page, I have a place where users can signup. This just takes to fields - Email and Password. When the submit button is clicked, they are taking to Signup.aspx, which shows a bigger signup form with fields for username, email, password, confirm password, etc. I would like to auto fill my email and password textboxes with those of the Default.aspx page that the user has entered. Is this possible? I'm using Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Then logically my title should only say "based on user input" ;)

Comment: No. The objection is to adding "metadata" to your title.

Comment: you can simply pass your email and password in querystring to signup page and access it on page load event of signup page and fill the textbox/

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do that.

- One way is to use **querystring** to navigate to like :

  `http://example.com/Signup.aspx?email=value1&password=value2`

  and get value on Signup.aspx  **Page_Load** event like :

  `String email = Request.QueryString["email"];`

  `String password = Request.QueryString["password"];`

  and assign to your text box controls like:

  `txtEmail.text =email;`

  `txtPassword=password;`

But posting password as clear text in query string is not good practice.

- Other way is to get HTTP **POST** information from the source page:

  1. In the source page, include a form element that contains HTML elements (such as input       or textarea) or ASP.NET server controls (such as TextBox or DropDownList controls) that post values when the form is submitted.
  2. In the target page, read the Form collection, which returns a dictionary of name/value pairs, one pair for each posted value. e.g.

//

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder displayValues = 
        new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection 
        postedValues = Request.Form;
    String nextKey;
    for(int i = 0; i < postedValues.AllKeys.Length; i++)
    {
        nextKey = postedValues.AllKeys[i];
        if(nextKey.Substring(0, 2) != "__")
        {
            displayValues.Append("<br>");
            displayValues.Append(nextKey);
            displayValues.Append(" = ");
            displayValues.Append(postedValues[i]);
        }
    }
   Label1.Text = displayValues.ToString();
}
```

- **Best** & **easiest** I think is to use **Session**:

  on `Submitbutton_click` event of Default.aspx, save values to Session like:

  `Session["Email"] = txtEmail.text;`

  `Session["Password"]=txtPassword.text;`

and retrieve values on `Signup.aspx` `Page_load` event like:

`string email = (string)(Session["Email"]);`

`string password = (string)(Session["Password"]);`

& assign to your control/textbox like:

`txtEmail.text =email;`

`txtPassword=password;`

There are more ways too to retrieve value from previous page like `PreviousPage.FindControl("txtEmail")` but I never like them.

Comment: What is going wrong with my code? On my default page, in the submitbutton_click event handler I have: Session("Email") = TextBoxEmail.Text     Then in my Signup page, in the onload handler, i have: Dim Email As String = Session("Email") /n NewTextBoxEmail.Text = Email. It's not displaying the text in the textbox as i would expect.

Comment: when i use the debugger, it gives me this error: Object reference not set to instance of an object.

Comment: You need to cast value from session to its corresponding datatype plus Check for null before using session something like `if(Session["Email"]!=null &&  !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["Email"])){\\Do your stuff}`